# How to change saturation values with opencv?

Tags: opencv

In order to add constant value to each pixel's saturation value, I do this in double loops. I wonder if there is any simpler and faster command achieving this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Mat img(200, 300, CV_8UC1);

Mat saturated;

double saturation = 10;
double scale = 1;

// what it does here is dst = (uchar) ((double)src*scale+saturation); 
img.convertTo(saturated, CV_8UC1, scale, saturation);
```

**EDIT**

If by saturation, you mean the S channel in a HSV image, you need to separe your image in three channels with `split()`, apply the saturation correction to the S channel, and then put them together with `merge()`.

Comment: The above function will work for any type of matrix, simply substitute CV_8UC1 for your type. The documentation for the convertTo function can be found [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-convertto)

Comment: Yes, if you want to treat only the S channel you would need to separate that first. As for which is quicker - I don't know, try both and see!

Comment: ConvertTo is definitely optimized, but the penalty of splitting and merging (with all the allocations involved) may he higher than the gain of using the optimized convert(). As Chris said, try and see.

Answer (score 14):

For the experiments I attempted, the alternative method of splitting hsv values, adjusting the individual channels and then doing a merge gave a better performance. Below is what worked for me many times faster as compared to looping through pixels:

```
(h, s, v) = cv2.split(imghsv)
s = s*satadj
s = np.clip(s,0,255)
imghsv = cv2.merge([h,s,v])
```

Note that I had converted the values to float32 during BGR2HSV transformation to avoid negative values during saturation transformation to due uint8 (default) overflow:

```
imghsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV).astype("float32")
```

And converted it back to default uint8 after my saturation adjustment:

```
imgrgb = cv2.cvtColor(imghsv.astype("uint8"), cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
```