# Java Android OpenCV - add saturation syntax

Tags: java, android, opencv

i don't how to add saturation in Java with openCV

```
List<Mat> channels = new LinkedList<>();
Core.split(imgMat, channels);

    // i can get saturation with channels.get(1) but how to add saturation ??

merge(channels, imgMat);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change saturation values with opencv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535650/how-to-change-saturation-values-with-opencv)

Comment: i already see this post and the corrected answer doesn't show how to implement saturation correction with merge and split in java, the third post doesn't look well with 2loop and doesn't know which language is used. The last is in python